# Company forcing to give previous company offer letter

Tags: job-offer, india

I joined a new company in India & they are forcing me to provide last companies offer letter holding my salary against it. My previous company is based in usa. I told my current company that offer letter are protected under NDA in usa but they are not listening at all. What should i do now to get my salary?

Is it mandatory for employees to provide previous offer letter in India & is it ok to hold salary against it?

Comment: Unfortunately, employee rights are quite limited in India. Be wary of answers that will answer from a USA perspective.

Comment: What do you mean by "get my salary"? Did you already do work for them and did not get paid for the work you did? Or are you still in negotiations and you want a specific salary in the future?

Comment: The ship may have already sailed on this idea - but you can't be made to give something which do do not have. I certainly don't have the offer letter for my current or previous employers, so if a future employer asked to see one then I'd simply reply that I no longer have it.

Comment: @nvoigt, I am working full time with them. After joining they asked me about previous offer letter. I simply said I signed NDA with previous company can't share sorry. They kept mum till month end. New month started & they said we can't process your salary due to missing document. So, now they are forcing me against my salary.

Comment: Yes, then indeed you need a lawyer.

Comment: Did you not sign an NDA (non-disclosure agreement) with the previous company?  You would be violating your NDA by sharing their private offer letter to you.   I even wonder if this is a trick question, they're testing how easily you can be talked into violating NDAs.  Also if this is a "virtual employer" (all your contacts via the Internet) this may be a scam.

Answer (score 5):

If you want legal advise (which looks like is the case), **talk to a lawyer**. Do not listen to random people on (or off, for that matter) internet.

That said, in general, there is no specific rule (in India) for providing previous company offer letter (or any confidential document, per se) for any purpose of a new job. If a background check (employment history) is concerned, a contact for the previous company should do the job. They should be able to verify whether you were employed with them for the period you claim. Other than that, any communication (including but not limited to offer letter, payslips, salary revision letter etc) which is/are marked confidential and under NDA need not be disclosed or presented.

Once again, in your current situation, you should talk to an employment lawyer to figure out the exact course of action. And next time, check the terms and conditions **before** signing the agreement / contract.

Comment: I don't know whether there were any terms and conditions handed out before that specified giving this information. It seems more likely to me that this just came as a random request from HR.

Comment: @quarague maybe. Usually we are habituated seeing these sort of weird requests before joining, it's rare _after_ joining.